# Keyboard shortcut for "Use another account" in RDP

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, windows-terminal-services

When using RDPing into a Windows Server 2008 server, it will often prompt you for credentials before you login. I noticed that tab will skip to the option to `Remember my credentials`, totally skipping Use another account.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to select `Use another account`?

[image: This here]

Comment: I've never noticed that. The "Use another account" option is completely omitted from the Tab order.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hoping someone had a kung fu way of doing that. I use RDP a lot I like keeping my hands on the keyboard as much as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The down arrow.

Also, I think you meant Tab instead of Shift in your post.

Answer (score -1):

Pressing the down arrow key shifts the control for the next user credentials.

Comment: How is this any better than the [other answer](http://serverfault.com/a/485298/218888) ?